# How did the Cold War contribute to the passing of the 1964 Civil Rights Act?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, political-history, social-history, civil-rights

I understand from Dudziak's "[Cold War Civil Rights](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691152431/cold-war-civil-rights)" that Soviet criticism of the US's civil rights record influenced the passing the [1964 Civil Rights Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Rights_Act_of_1964). However, I was wondering if there were other ways that the Cold War contributed to the bill's passing. For instance, did the American public feel ashamed of its racial crises in the midst of the Cold War's ideological war, leading to public support for the bill? Did the US government, seeing the movement as communist, seek to appease it before things escalated?

Comment: What sort of factors would you find compelling?

Comment: *Public opinion* is the crucial factor, especially in democracies, where it literally determines who comes to power.

Comment: Hi all, I apologize for the poor question and have revised it accordingly. My focus is now on the Cold War's impact on civil rights

Comment: You're on the verge of an interesting question here.  How are the three thesis different?   What evidence would you seek for each thesis and where would you look for this evidence?  Do any of the following help: [study.com](https://study.com/learn/lesson/cold-war-civil-rights.html#:~:text=Civil%20Rights%20Act%20of%201964), [Skrenty](https://www.jstor.org/stable/657868), or [Tobias](https://scholarship.richmond.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1639&context=law-faculty-publications)

Comment: There is nothing particularly *socialist* in civil rights - they are inherent to liberalism/capitalism. In fact, if we adopt Marxist view of socialism (practiced in the USSR) - equal rights are the foundation of the capitalist society and the reason for inequality (since anyone with financial, intellectual, physical or other advantage would advance further.) Thus, Marxist version of socialism seeks to abolish the equal rights, giving advantages to those who, in Marx' opinion, are the producers of wealth - this is termed *dictatorship of the proletariat*.

Comment: It is true though that socialists of non-Marxist strain did strive for equal rights as a way to improving social conditions - notably the Marx' friend and arch-rival Ferdinand Lassalle, for whom the universal suffrage was the cornerstone of socialism. German Social Democrats (SDP), although paying lip service to Marx, essentially followed the path outlined by Lassalle.

Comment: It would probably help if you explained why you expect the answers to any of those questions to be yes.

Comment: Hi Vadim, I believe that the true character of the movement is not relevant to my question. What does matters is how the rest of America viewed it, and there is some evidence that it did indeed see the movement as communist. I apologize if I created any confusion by calling it socialist https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/communism

Comment: @DrewH.Anderson Marx himself used terms *Socialism/Communism* interchangeably, and much of the modern debates about socialism can be reduced to different meaning given to these terms in the Communist states and in the West (none of western "socialists" states actually calls itself this way - they are social democracies, while the Soviet constitution indeed defined the USSR as socialist.) So the extent to which it mattered in the US is that *socialism* and fight for racial equality are both "leftist things".

Answer (score -1):

As I have pointed out in the comments, civil rights are quite *liberal/capitalist* concept, so emancipation had to happen eventually, even without any pressure exerted by the USSR.

However, the USSR did support some leading figures in the civil rights movement: e.g., [Angela Davies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Davis) was twice a vice-presidential candidate from the Communist Party, and actively mingled with Soviet and other East European leaders. In this sense, passing the Civil Rights act was likely making the Communists movements less relevant, and served to diminish their influence.

Comment: Your first paragraph is basically right.  The second, though, not so much. Soviet meddling (which is how it would have been perceived) in domestic politics would only harm what it nominally supported.

Comment: @MarkOlson this seems to me like a subjective judgement - co-opting the civil rights movement could damage the cause of the civil rights in the eyes of anti-Communists, i.e., the right-wing, but it likely made communism seem more palatable to those who supported civil rights. From the point of the USSR - it probably simple sought to induce political instability, just like today Russia supports extreme right-wing and left-wing parties (while the US fosters various "pro-democracy" movements in Russia.)

Comment: At the risk of discussion in comments, Soviet meddling would only have harmed what it supported if it were interested in working with the system.  The goal wasn't civil rights, the goal was the triumph of communism over capitalism. Civil rights and Angela Davies, et. al. were only weapons in that struggle.

Comment: Well, sure. And your second paragraph is no less. The problem with questions like this is they are virtually impossible to answer objectively even at book-length. I lived through it all and this is what I observed.

Comment: @MCW I am not really sure whether post-ww2 Soviet leaders really believed in the victory of the Communism. It seems that, already starting with Stalin, spreading of the communism was a tool for promoting Soviet national interests.

Comment: Angela Davis is not a good example. She was not a leading civil rights figure; furthermore, her fame (or infamy) came only in 1970s, well after the passage of the 1964 Civil Rights Act.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you are welcome to propose what you consider a "good example".

Comment: Belafonte, for instance, or Robeson in the early days.

Comment: @MoisheKohan these are artists, who engaged in some activism. Sure, Soviet propaganda made much of them, but they are relatively unknown in the West. Davis was a leading intellectual, vice-presidential candidate, whose contribution to civil rights is continued to be praised even nowadays (despite her obvious association with Communism and questionable remarks about Soviet refuseniks.)

Answer (score -1):

There were a number of things contributing to the push for civil rights up to 1964.

For a start, the Americans themselves had fought a civil war in the 1860s largely over the status of black slave labour.

The practice of slavery had already been outlawed in Europe since time immemorial, and America was a European settler colony. So the USA was already on a long trajectory towards establishing the same civil rights as prevailed in Europe.

By the 1930s, the USSR was really at the forefront of developing what we nowadays think of as ideal "liberal rights" enjoyed by all citizens. It was a political union that drew together a large number of ethnic communities (at a time when racism in many nations was otherwise at a high), and as an aside it also promoted the rights and capabilities of women as workers too.

This also had an influence on how for example Britain mobilised women into industry at the outbreak of WW2.

For the American civil rights movement however, there were several consequences of WW2 itself.

Firstly, black soldiers were mobilised abroad in large numbers, and this broadened their horizons and often exposed them to European populations (like the British) who did not generally have the prejudicial attitudes of the American south (which was still frankly reeling economically from the civil war, and plagued by everyday racism).

Secondly, as veterans having fought for the American state, a new generation not only were equipped with military skills, but also naturally developed a sense of confidence and moral righteousness in demanding equal treatment.

Thirdly, at the conclusion of WW2, racist ideologies amongst ruling classes had been dealt a terrible blow, not only by the defeat of Hitler as one of its main representatives, but by the horrors perpetrated by his regime in the meantime. It became unpopular and clearly dangerous to the ruling classes themselves to keep promoting the lies of racial ideologies which both provoked uncontrollable conflicts and only weakened those who adhered most strongly to those lies.

In the post-WW2 era when the USA was really becoming concerned about the influence of communism and the USSR, together with the increased endogenous strength of the civil rights movement for the reasons just stated, this was why progress towards better civil rights became irresistible, and the resistance against no longer tenable.

Comment: Much of what you wrote is simply wrong.